# Is there an equivalent to bash's <() in sh

Tags: node.js, bash

I'm trying to a node.js program that redirects to bash.
The command contains a string like this.

```
var virtualFile  = '<( cat <<EndOfText\n' + fileContents + 'EndOfText\n)';
```

However, when I redirect it, the sh freaks out at that text, before running bash.

I was wondering if '<()' has an equivalent in sh. Thanks

Comment: Why do you need all that complication? Can't you just use the here-doc directly?

Comment: It's called [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution). It isn't POSIX, so there's no equivalent in `sh`. After all that, are you going to do `< <(cat ... )`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using process substitution (`<(...)`) to create a named pseudo-file which you can provide on the command line to a utility which *also* reads its `stdin`, then you should seriously consider just putting the contents (`fileContents`) into a temporary file. On most modern systems, that will turn out to be reasonably performant. Its other advantages are that it is easy and compatible with all shells, not only those that try to be Posix-compatible.

On the other hand, if you just need to feed `fileContents` into a utility and you can use stdin for that purpose, then you've got way too much machinery. Just use the here-doc itself (`'<<EndMarker\n' + fileContents + 'EndMarker\n'`)